# Installing mod_proxy_html on docker httpd 2.1

Tags: apache, docker, httpd.conf, mod-proxy-html

I'm currently working on my reverse proxy using docker image httpd 2.4. I followed this [guide](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies) to configure the httpd.conf.

However, I am currently stuck at configuring ProxyHTMLURLMap. This needed the module mod_proxy_html.so which is not included in the image.

Do you have any idea on how I can add this in to the Docker image?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Edit: should be docker httpd 2.4

Comment: This issue https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/issues/14 was filed, and then closed, but it doesn't appear the fix resolved the issue.   I ended up using a different container (ubuntu 16.04) and building apache on top of it using something similar to what is documented here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/

Comment: It looks like they addressed this issue with this fix: https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/pull/34